# .NET build adding unwanted characters to product version of the .exe file

Tags: c#, .net, build, version

Recently, my .exe file have been built with a unwanted `Product Version` metadata after build.
Here's the project configuration:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.8.9.28</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.8.9.28</FileVersion>
    <Version>1.8.9.28</Version>
    <PackageIcon>icon.ico</PackageIcon>
    <PackageIconUrl />
    <ApplicationIcon>icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But after I build the application, the file's Product Version becomes something like `1.8.9.28+4263e2bb89fab0e2a2ac67af575c54ecf934eac5`

That have been happening both in Visual Studio Community 2022 build and Azure Dev Ops build.
My distributed application uses the `Product Version` to check for updates, but, with this string pattern, the application is unable to instanciate a new `Version` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the line blow to project config and the mentioned behavior will be disabled

```
<IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>false</IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>
```